# Problem inserting a complicated equation into a (tikz) node

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, nodes

I have a problem inserting an equation into a tikz node. I'm used to insert successive equations that are separated with 'align', but with my equation (succesive lines, put together with two braces), I does not work, I cannot seem to find the answer to this. I'm using: `tikz`, `tikzlibrary`, `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `amsmath`.
I think the problem is with the two braces, and the encapsulated equation...

```
\begin{equation}

if \;  

  \left\{  
      \begin{aligned}
        x_{ref}=x_1+1\\
        x_{ref}=x_2+1\\
        x_{ref}=x_3+1\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right\rbrace 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Can you complete your example code so that it's compilable? Just the minimum to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think you can insert `equation` in a node; but `if $\left\{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right\}$` should do.

Comment: Thank you #egreg, it worked. I think it was a problem with the dollar signs!!

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible problems. The only obvious problem in your snippet is that you have empty lines inside the `equation` environment, which is not permitted.

That said, egreg is correct in saying that you cannot have an `equation` environment inside a node, *unless* you set the `text width` of the node. That makes the `node` a `minipage` like box, and makes it possible to use `equation`. You could of course also add a `minipage` inside the `node`, but that is more messy, I think.

In the code below I also added egreg's suggestion of inline math.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [text width=5cm]  {\begin{equation*}
\text{if }  
  \left\lbrace
      \begin{aligned}
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_1+1\\
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_2+1\\
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_3+1\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right\rbrace 
\end{equation*}};

\node at (6,0) {if $ \left\lbrace
      \begin{aligned}
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_1+1\\
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_2+1\\
        x_{\mathrm{ref}}=x_3+1\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right\rbrace$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```